# Evaluate mathematic expression in cron

Tags: bash, cron

I want to name file according to parity of a day of a week.
In the terminal the following works: `$(($(date +\%u)%2))`

But this doesn't work in cron (I suspect evaluating of mathematical expressions doesn't work).

How can I make this working in cron?

Comment: Are you putting this expression in the actual crontab? Or is it in a shell script called from the crontab? If it's a shell script, does it have `#!/bin/sh` at the top?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You escaped one percent sign and not the other:

```
$(($(date +\%u)%2))
               ^
              HERE
```

*All* percent signs in a crontab entry need to be escaped, because % has special meaning there. To quote from the crontab(5) manpage:

> The  entire  command  portion  of the line, up to a newline or % character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL  variable of the crontab file.  Percent-signs (%) in the command,unless escaped with backslash (), will be changed into newline characters, and  all  data  after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input.

<sup>*Admittedly, that paragraph could be worded better.*</sup>

So that needs to be:

```
$(($(date +\%u)\%2))
```

Answer (score 4):

From [`crontab(5)`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab)

> Several  environment  variables are set up automatically by the cron(8)
>   daemon.  SHELL is set to /bin/sh,

and `sh` don't know nothing about them fancy maths. This suggests two possible solutions; first, to set `SHELL` to some other shell such as `SHELL=/bin/bash` or instead to keep the cron file uncomplicated, and call a script that then contains whatever date math business logic is necessary. (`%` is also special according to `crontab(5)`, by the way)

Comment: `$(( expr ))` math is in POSIX; /bin/sh should support it. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04

Comment: My `sh` don't support it; I do not assume some flavor of POSIX by default. And, regardless, why complicate the crontab file with such hard-to-test code? Put that business logic elsewhere, somewhere that is easy to write unit tests for.

Comment: And: which is your sh? then. Does it print a 2 with `echo $((1+1))`?,

Comment: @Arrow I write all my `sh` code for the heirloom borne shell, it fails on such things as `$(...`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, [the heirloom shell does not understand any of the $(…) syntax](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh/sh.1.html).

Answer (score 1):

Create two cron entries.

One which runs on days with zero parity (use the 'day of week' field in crontab) which writes to file named with zero.  And another which runs on days with one parity, which writes to file named with one.